# jquery .on not loading

Tags: jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [infinite scroll javascript already fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139508/infinite-scroll-javascript-already-fired)

When a user hovers over a div with class .item_list_image I want other divs to show, I'm trying the following but simply not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("body").on("mouseenter", ".list_item_image", function () {
        {
                $(this).children(".gl_view2").show();
                $(this).children(".gl_relist").show();
        });

   $("body").on("mouseleave", ".list_item_image", function () {
       {
                $(this).children(".gl_view2").hide();
                $(this).children(".gl_relist").hide();
       });
</script>
```

I have been advised to use the .on method as I am using jquery infinite scroll and therefore appending the html on the shown page, with new items being added containing divs with class list_item_image

Comment: Your code is valid. There must be something else wrong. Tried logging if the function fires when you enter/leave the objects?

Comment: You already opened this discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139508/infinite-scroll-javascript-already-fired/12139556

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed `$(document).ready`, just wrap your code with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on("mouseenter", ".list_item_image", function (){
        $(this).children(".gl_view2").show();
        $(this).children(".gl_relist").show();
    })
    .on("mouseleave", ".list_item_image", function (){
       $(this).children(".gl_view2").hide();
       $(this).children(".gl_relist").hide(); 
    });
});​
```

Also noteice the extra `{` in your both functions at the top just bottom of the `$("body")`.

[**Just an example**](http://jsfiddle.net/8weGV/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Check brackets of your code.
try this

```
 $("body").on("mouseenter", ".list_item_image", function() {
     {
         //alert('dsfs');
         $(this).children(".gl_view2").show();
         $(this).children(".gl_relist").show();
     }});

 $("body").on("mouseleave", ".list_item_image", function() {
     {
         $(this).children(".gl_view2").hide();
         $(this).children(".gl_relist").hide();
     }});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put your code in dom ready.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
                    $("body").on("mouseenter", ".list_item_image", function () {
                    {
                        $(this).children(".gl_view2").show();
                        $(this).children(".gl_relist").show();
                    });

                    $("body").on("mouseleave", ".list_item_image", function () {
                    {
                        $(this).children(".gl_view2").hide();
                        $(this).children(".gl_relist").hide();
                    });
})
            </script>
```

Also You can achieve the same thing via this code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
                        $(".list_item_image").hover(function () {
                        {
                            $(this).children(".gl_view2").show();
                            $(this).children(".gl_relist").show();
                        },

                        function () {
                        {
                            $(this).children(".gl_view2").hide();
                            $(this).children(".gl_relist").hide();
                        });
    })
                </script>
```

Comment: read the full documentation . Don't get confused with .hover()

Comment: you're right, overread you wrote .hover() there

Answer (score 0):

you have two `{{` open brackets on each handler function and this is a sintax error.

Use just one `{`