# Infinite scrolling

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I am trying to add some "Infinite Scrolling" to my product pages. However, i can't get it working at all, so i have nothing.
The page currently works, but it just outputs all of the products. I can't get the infinite scrolling scripts i found working, as my query is not always the same.

This is the code that builds my query, using GETs:

```
$kategori_q = "";
if ($kategori !== "") {
    if ($hkat !== "") {
        $ukator = "";
        $underkategorier = sqlSelect("SELECT * FROM underkategorier WHERE fk_hkategori = '$kategori'");
        while ($row = sqlFetch($underkategorier)) {
            $ukator .= " fk_ukategori = '".$row['underkategori_id']."' OR"; 
        }
        $kategori_q = rtrim($ukator, "OR");
        $kategori_q = "WHERE ($kategori_q)";
    }
    else {
        $kategori_q = "WHERE fk_ukategori = '$kategori'";
    }
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM annoncer $kategori_q ORDER BY annonce_id DESC";

$soeg = "";
if (isset($_GET['soeg'])) {
    $soeg = $_GET['soeg'];
    if (substr_count($query, "WHERE") == 1) {
        $soeg = " AND (overskrift LIKE '%$soeg%' OR beskrivelse LIKE '%$soeg%')";
    }
    else {
        $soeg = " WHERE (overskrift LIKE '%$soeg%' OR beskrivelse LIKE '%$soeg%')";
    }
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM annoncer $kategori_q $soeg ORDER BY annonce_id DESC";
$q = sqlSelect($query);
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139508/infinite-scroll-javascript-already-fired

Comment: This won't help answer your question, but how does `sqlSelect()` work? It looks like a custom function. Does it utilize `mysql_*`?

Comment: It's just the mysql_select() i changed the name on :-)

Comment: PLEASE don't take user input and blindly insert it into SQL queries! You're script is vulnerable to SQL injection. See http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php for an explanation of the problem. There are many fixes for this, but a simple solution for SQL injection is to use PHP Data Objects (PDO) and let it take care of escaping automatically. See quick examples at http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php then read up on PDO and PDOStatement more thoroughly.

Comment: Doesn't mysql_real_escape avoid sql injections?

Comment: @PatrickReck Yes it can, but you must use it properly. You're not calling `mysql_real_escape` here, and it's very easy to forget to use it. **It's much safer to make your own function that uses PDO/PDOStatement**. You can make a simple function that takes the SQL query as a string with question marks and the query parameters as variable-length arguments. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php for variable-length arguments. Then you can just call it like this in a single line: `$result = mySafeSelect("SELECT * FROM table WHERE category = ? AND page = ?", $kategori, $soeg);`